# Windows 7 desktop icons all appear as Word icon and try to open in Word 2010

Tags: windows-7

All my desktop shortcuts look like the Word icon.  When I use a shortcut to try to open a program, Word 2010 opens and then it tries to open the program so a file conversion window appears!  What's going on?  How do I get the shortcuts back?

Comment: Have you tried System Restore?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to start menu.
2. Run command
3. `regedit` in run command.
4. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\filexts\`
5. Search for .`lnk` ext.
6. Delete whole `.lnk` key or delete the `userchioce` key on that.
7. Just restart.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like somehow all of your file associations got mixed up (or more accurately they're all assigned to Word).  It's a bit of a hassle, but your best bet is to change the associations one at a time, on an "as needed" basis.

What you do is right-click the file in question, say: `mynotes.txt`, and hover over the `Open With` menu, and select `Choose default program`.  You can then select the program that you want to open it with (from then on).  Just make sure that `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file` is ticked on the 'Open with' dialog.

If you want to get down and dirty, you can also go to the control panel, and search for 'File Associations' and select the `Change the file type associated with a file extension' item.  There you can change all the associations on the system.

Unfortunately I don't know of a simple and safe way to reset all assocations all at once.

Answer (score 1):

You may import following registry hives from "good" computer (where links are working OK):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile]
```

OR
In case you have not machine with Win 7 where it works nearby, you may save text below into a file with .reg extension and import it into registry via duble-click on this file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk]
@="lnkfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{00021500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
"Handler"="{ceefea1b-3e29-4ef1-b34c-fec79c4f70af}"
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
31,00,36,00,37,00,36,00,39,00,00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30397"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30318"
"NullFile"=""
"Command"=-

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew\Config]
"DontRename"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile]
@="Shortcut"
"EditFlags"=dword:00000001
"FriendlyTypeName"="@shell32.dll,-4153"
"NeverShowExt"=""
"IsShortcut"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\CLSID]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\IconHandler]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.lnk\UserChoice]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [File Association Fixer](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/file-association-fixer-for-windows-7-vista-released)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the problem:

1. Open the *Run* dialog (*Start → Run* or <kbd>[image] (Win)</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Type `regedit`, then click `[OK]` or type <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`
4. Look for a `.lnk` branch
5. If you find one, delete it
6. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Go to start menu.
Run command `regedit`.
In `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\filexts`
Search for `.lnk` ext.

Delete whole `.lnk` key or delete the `userchoice` key on that.

Restart.

Answer (score -1):

1.open the RUN dialog Box

2.Type There regedit

3.HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts

4.find .lnk

5.Delete userChoice

Comment: Looks a lot like the answer from 1½ years ago.